# How to include two URL in json ajax

Tags: ajax, json

Currently, the searchform hit, the form get submitted. Then it will fetch data from specified URL which is search/ajax2.php and return data here.

All I want to add is, to include another URL beside the above mentioned one, so that two actions can be performed at the same time.

Now, in the search/ajax2.php it runs a select query. Whereas in additional page that I want to include, which could be writedb.php it inserts data taken from this jason into database. It doesn't have to return anything back to ajax page though!

How to achieve this?

```
 $("#searchform").on("submit", function () {
        //$(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled','disabled');
        var data = {
            "action": "test"
        };

    data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "search/ajax2.php",
        data: data,

        success: function (data) {

}
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try  adding your second url in sucess function like this :

```
$.ajax({ 
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'some_url1',
  data: 'some data', 
  success: function(data){  
    $.ajax ({  
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'some_url2',
      data: 'some data',
      success: function(data){}
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I tried your code, only the first placed url works, the second doesn't...why