# jquery tow function in same script

Tags: jquery, ajax

Need to define multiple `jquery` functions in same `<script>` here my script and it is not working.  but I tested `ajax` function separately and it is working.

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        function loadList()

        function loadList() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/getVoucherajax",
//       data:{}
            });
        }


    });
</script>
```

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30567757/how-to-include-two-url-in-json-ajax/30569442#30569442)

Comment: same function name? loadList()?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this

```
<script>
    $(function () {

       loadList1()
       loadList2()

        function loadList1() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/function1",
            });
        }

        function loadList2() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/function2",
            });
        }   

    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove extra `function loadList() {` from your code:

```
$(function () {
    function loadList() {
        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/getVoucherajax",
        });
    }

    loadList(); // Call it here
});
```

Answer (score 1):

if your are trying to call a function you should not include function word again or you could try this.

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        loadList();

        function loadList() {
            $.ajax({
                method: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>login/getVoucherajax",
//       data:{}
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```